# SQL Vlookup Value in Same Table to Get Value From Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, left-join, ssms, window-functions

I have a table (`gbfol_det`) that contains three columns and a second table (`argcloy_h`) that contains one column.

I need to do similar to an Excel VLOOKUP. I want to check for `posting_code = 'gcs'` and then find the associated `gsp` posting by using `breakdown_link`. From there it should grab the associated `card_number` from that `gsp` row.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT '[dbo].[gbfol_det]' AS 'TABLE_NAME', det.folio_number, det.breakdown_link, det.posting_code, '[dbo].[argcloy_h]' AS 'TABLE_NAME', gc.card_number
FROM gbfol_det det
LEFT JOIN argcloy_h gc ON det.folio_number = gc.folio_number
```

which returns the following data:

| TABLE_NAME | folio_number | breakdown_link | posting_code | TABLE_NAME | card_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [dbo].[gbfol_det] | 501990 | 734210 | gsp | [dbo].[argcloy_h] | 12062000020615 |
| [dbo].[gbfol_det] | 501993 | 734210 | pmc | [dbo].[argcloy_h] | NULL |
| [dbo].[gbfol_det] | 501993 | 734210 | gcs | [dbo].[argcloy_h] | NULL |

My desired outcome is the following:

| TABLE_NAME | folio_number | breakdown_link | posting_code | TABLE_NAME | card_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [dbo].[gbfol_det] | 501990 | 734210 | gsp | [dbo].[argcloy_h] | 12062000020615 |
| [dbo].[gbfol_det] | 501993 | 734210 | pmc | [dbo].[argcloy_h] | NULL |
| [dbo].[gbfol_det] | 501993 | 734210 | gcs | [dbo].[argcloy_h] | 12062000020615 |

I've tried doing a subquery (second SELECT in the SELECT statement) and also tried doing some CASE WHEN SELECT but couldn't get either to work.

Comment: Sample data would help immensely

Comment: @Charlieface I may be misunderstanding but the sample data is the stuff in the tables.

Comment: @WolfieeifloW: the tables in your question would correspond to the current and desired results. But this does not give much more than clues on how your data is actually structured in the underlying table (that's what we call sample data).

Comment: Your expected data looks same as the data you're currently getting. No? Vlookup is just a sub query with top 1.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score -1):

As I understand your question, you are looking to compute the card number of each `'gcs'` row, by bringing the corresponding value from the `'gsp'` row that has the same `breakdown_link`.

If so, I would recommend window functions and `case`:

```
SELECT '[dbo].[gbfol_det]' AS 'TABLE_NAME', 
    det.folio_number, 
    det.breakdown_link, 
    det.posting_code, 
    '[dbo].[argcloy_h]' AS 'TABLE_NAME', 
    CASE det.posting_code
        WHEN 'gcs' THEN MAX(CASE WHEN det.posting_code = 'gsp' THEN gc.card_number END) OVER(PARTITION BY det.breakdown_link)
        ELSE gc.card_number
    END as card_number
FROM gbfol_det det
LEFT JOIN argcloy_h gc ON det.folio_number = gc.folio_number
```

Answer (score -2):

It's really hard to understand exactly what you're doing without sample data. Your description also makes little sense, as you're claiming argcloy_h has just one column, while you join on folio_number and get card_number into the select list. So that's at least 2.

I'll assume you want to do the following:

1. For the rows in gbfol_det with posting_code = gsp, that have a corresponding folio_number in argcloy_h, find the card_number from there
2. For the rows in gbfol_det with posting_code = gcs, find the corresponding row in the same table with posting_code = gsp and the same breakdown_link

There's a couple way you can achieve that, either join argclov_h twice, once directly, and once through the gsp row, or use a CTE and then self join that CTE to find the matching gsp row for gcs rows. Here's the second scenario because I enjoy CTEs:

```
with gsp_resolved as (
   select det.folio_number, det.breakdown_link, det.posting_type, gc.card_number
     from gbfol_det det
     left outer
     join argcloy_h gc 
      on det.folio_number = gc.folio_number -- match by folio number
     and det.posting_type = 'gsp' -- for gsp rows
)
select gsp_resolved.folio_number, gsp_resolved.breakdown_link, gsp_resolved.posting_type
     , coalesce(gsp_resolved.card_number, gsp_for_gcs.card_number) as card_number -- either use own resolved card number, or take from the corresponding gsp row
  from gsp_resolved 
  left outer 
  join gsp_resolved gsp_for_gcs
    on gsp_resolved.posting_type = 'gcs' -- for my gcs rows
   and gsp_for_gcs.posting_type = 'gsp' -- get me a gsp row
   and gsp_for_gcs.breakdown_link = gsp_resolved.breakdown_link -- with a matching breakdown_link
```

[Live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/VTx-FlcB)